# Image Color Doesn't Match Background Color - Gmail Only on iOS

Tags: ios, gmail, html-email

The rounded corners of the following screenshot is one .gif image that is a solid color #f1f1f2. It resides in its own table above another table using the same color as the background color: #f1f1f2.

However, in Gmail on the iPhone and iPad (so iOS), the image appears to be a different color, #f7f3f7.

I've checked all other email clients, as well as viewed the email as an html page in several web browsers; I'm not able to replicate the issue. I resliced the image and re-uploaded to an image hosting server with no luck.

Anyone familiar with this issue and how to resolve it? Thanks.

[image: image issue gmail on iOS]

Answer (score 0):

Fastest solution was to use a jpg instead of gif.